# Not able to play MP4 file created using MFT

Tags: media, encode, h.264, ms-media-foundation

I am trying to create MP4  file using msdn [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff819476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).I am using the same code no change.I am  using Logitech H264 camera.The code is able to create the file and save video data but its not playing.I tried in media player and vlc as well but no success.

I am not able figure out whether it is due to camera or I am missing something here ?

Comment: That's a Transcode example, maybe a little code would be good to see what you have changed to capture. I don't know if you can really live-capture with this code. Have you tried to capture with WMV or do you have a Logitech C920 which encodes h264 already in the camera?

Comment: Any sample content to share?